# как сделать симуляцию используя turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle

Я хотел создать симуляцию при условии, что есть три точки, то есть треугольник и четвертая точка, которые изначально могут быть где угодно. а в бумажном варианте вам нужно бросить куб 1,2, это 4 точки, делающие шаг в сторону первых 3,4, в сторону вторых 5 или 6, в сторону третьей вершины треугольника . и посмотрите, какую картинку рисует 4 точки

```
import turtle
from random import randrange, randint
from turtle import*

bgcolor('black')
color('blue')
axcoardinate = randint(-500,500)
aycoardinate = randint(-500,500)
bxcoardinate = randint(-500,500)
bycoardinate = randint(-500,500)
cxcoardinate = randint(-500,500)
cycoardinate = randint(-500,500)
for i in range(100):
       wasd = randint(1,6)
       if wasd <3:
                turtle.goto(axcoardinate,aycoardinate)

       elif wasd <5:
                turtle.goto(bxcoardinate,bycoardinate)

       elif wasd <7:
                turtle.goto(cxcoardinate,cycoardinate)
```

но тут надо чтобы он не полностью перемещался к точке а например на 5%

Comment: а нельзя ли вопрос на русский перевести?

Comment: что именно непонятно?

Comment: Именно? ничего не понятно.  начиная с фразы "а в бумажном варианте" идет просто набор слов, понятный только вам.

Comment: ок смотри. кидаешь кубик и четвертая точка делает шаг в сторону одной из трех вершин треугольника. если на кубике выпадает 1 или 2 то четвертая точка делает шаг к первой вершине ю если на кубике выпало 3 или 4 то в сторону второй вершины и если 5 или 6 то идешь в сторону 3 вершины

Comment: очень хорошо. а теперь это пояснение добавьте вместо сумбура в тексте вопроса.